# Saved pre-train model layer weights but cannot load the weights through H5PY

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have been trying to save the weights of my neural network model so that I could use a few of its layers for another neural network model to be trained on another dataset.

pre-trained model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(X_train_orig_sm.shape)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

model.summary()
# need sparse otherwise shape is wrong. check why
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Fitting the data to the model')
batch_size = 20
epochs = 10
history = model.fit(X_train_orig_sm, Y_train_orig_sm, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
print('Evaluating the test data on the model')
```

How I saved the weights of neural network:

```
model.save_weights("dnn_model.h5")
```

How I try to load the weights of neural network:

```
dnn_model=model.load_weights("dnn_model.h5")
dnn_model.layers[5]
```

While trying to load the model, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

I dont seem to understand why the layers of the neural network are not recognised even though the pre-trained neural network is trained before the model was saved. Any advice, solution or direction will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `model.save_weights("dnn_model.h5")`, you only save the "weights" of the model. You do not save the actual structure of the model. That's why you cannot access the layers etc.

To save the actual model, you can call the below.

```py
# save
model.save('dnn_model') # save as pb
model.save('dnn_model.h5') # save as HDF5

# load
dnn_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('dnn_model') # load as pb
dnn_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('dnn_model.h5') # load as HDF5
```

Note: You do not need to add an extension to the name to save as pb.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load